# Program fails to load in simulator beyond splashscreen

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

based on the MVVM Light 4 beta template I created a 7.5 app and just put a listbox on the mainpage. No other pages. I created a ResourceDictionary with some styles. In the designer, the mainpage shows nicely with some sample data.

But when I run the app, the simulator starts the app but stalls at the splashscreen (the default grey clock).

When I step through the UI I see nothing wrong, it goes through the whole initialisation as far as I can see.

How can I debug such as situation further?

Comment: If you're still stuck on this, zip your project up and post a link to it. I'd be glad to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to set and hit a break point at `Application_Launching` in App.xaml.cs? If not, try setting up a new MVVM Light 4 project and slowly add the existing pieces from your problem application to the new project (making sure it runs each time) until you hit your exception.

Comment: Yeah, what I did was create a fresh new project and then slowly added back the pieces. With the EXACT same code for the DataService, ViewModel, MainPage XAML and style ResourceDictionary, it now runs! Still extremely weird that the old project did not want to startup....